# Modal Dialog: Navigate back to parent folder

Tags: document-library, navigation

I have opened up a SharePoint modal dialog to show document library. The Document library contains a hierarchy of folders.

When I reach to the 2nd level of folders there is no option to go back to the parent folder. How can we get such an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting the helpful response above aside...
What we need is for Microsoft to deliver a usable product, 'out of the box', that has a navigate to parent folder/back button.

Answer (score 2):

Jon,

What you need is a Breadcrumb control for your Document Library view, there are some available:

For SharePoint 2010:

[SharePoint 2010: Bread Crumb for List/Library View Web Part in Wiki Page.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18196.sharepoint-2010-bread-crumb-for-listlibrary-view-web-part-in-wiki-page.aspx)

[Adding a Breadcrumb to Document Library Web Parts in Sharepoint 2010](http://alexis.nomine.fr/en/blog/2013/12/28/adding-breadcrumb-document-library-web-parts-sharepoint-2010/)

For SharePoint 2013:

[SharePoint 2013: Breadcrumb for list/library](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-folder-navigation-for.html)

PS: A similar question [Document library breadcrumb](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/document-library-breadcrumb)

Comment: i have tried first link for sharepoint 2010.but not working

Comment: Did you try second..